# Active Record doing nothing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

please I need a little help... I don't know what I'm doing wrong but I need just a simple select query with Active Record. This looks my code:

Model:

```
class Kiosk < ApplicationRecord
    @kiosk = Kiosk.all
end
```

Controller:

```
class KioskController < ApplicationController
    def kiosk
        @kiosk = Kiosk.all
    end
end
```

HAML:

```
#@kiosk
```

And it just doing nothing. Even if I change a password of database there isn't any error with connection. rake db:migrade was done a db was created.

Thanks

Comment: "a db was created" - but are there any kiosks in the db?

Comment: Your model doesn't look good. `class Kiosk` and inside - `Kiosk.all`. How do you imagine it?

Comment: 1) wrong code in model. 2) not clear what is in routes.rb

Comment: You right, I had bad routes, I change it to resources and now working! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at your logs (eg Rails.root => logs/development.log) or the output in your terminal – are there any error messages? If you log in to your console with eg `rails console` and run `@kiosks = Kiosk.all` – what are you seeing? or how about `Kiosk.count` –– is it showing that there are any kiosks? As mentioned the model looks funny... not sure why you have the `@kiosk = Kiosk.all` line in there at all....

Comment: irb(main):001:0> @kiosks = Kiosk.all
  Kiosk Load (2.3ms)  SELECT `kiosks`.* FROM `kiosks`
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Kiosk id: 1, name: "test", whid: "test", link: "test", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>]>

Comment: Ok so ActiveRecord is working. It sounds like maybe there's confusion around the controller and view? Is the kiosk method in your controller mapping to a route in your routes.rb file? Is there a view that's rendering the @kiosk variable, eg kiosk/kios.html.erb? If so what does that view look like? In your terminal output or log files – what is Rails saying is happening, eg did it render a certain template?